# Laravel 4: DB::select with IN statment

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4

when run laravel DB::select with IN statment, as documented:

```
//$list_of_ids = '1,3,5,66,3'
//$uid = 1

DB::select('
    SELECT SUM(score)
    FROM user
    WHERE id
    IN (?)
    and user_id = ?
    LIMIT 4
', array($list_of_ids,$uid));
```

not receive any results

but when run:

```
DB::select('
    SELECT SUM(score)
    FROM user
    WHERE id
    IN ('.$list_of_ids.')  //add var here
    and user_id = ?
    LIMIT 4
', array($uid));
```

return correct results, what is the matter in first way?

Comment: Here's an explanation why this doesn't work [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition). The short version is that it isn't related to Laravel, but PDO itself.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to to is use an actual array and a proper Query.

```
$userIds = explode(',', $list_of_ids);
DB::table('user')->whereIn('id', $userIds)->where('user_id', $uid)->limit(4)->get([DB::raw('SUM(score)')]);
```